# Why does “signInAudience”: “AzureADMultipleOrgs” cause 'The URI scheme is invalid or unsupported'

Tags: azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito

I am getting an error when trying to switch the Supported account types to: **Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)**

I am using as IdentifierUris the amazon cognito urn:amazon:cognito:sp:XXXXXXXXXXX

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eopox.png)

Comment: Multi-tenant apps enforce stricter requirements on URIs if I remember correctly. Why are you switching this app to multi-tenant? You want to allow any Azure AD organisation to sign in through your Cognito?

Comment: at the moment only the accounts of my organization can sign in through my Cognito, but i want to allow any organization

Comment: @SaidRahmani had you got this working with cognito? It seems cognito is using  `urn:amazon:cognito:sp:XXXXXXXXXXX` by default as the ID, which's not supported in Azure (when mutitenant)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a single tenant application, it is sufficient for the App ID URI to **be unique within that tenant**.

For a multi-tenant application, it must be **globally unique** so Azure AD can find the application across all tenants. Global uniqueness is enforced by requiring the App ID URI to have **a host name that matches a verified domain of the Azure AD tenant**.

If the name of your tenant was `contoso.onmicrosoft.com` then a valid App ID URI would be `https://contoso.onmicrosoft.com/myapp`. If your tenant had a verified domain of `contoso.com`, then a valid App ID URI would also be `https://contoso.com/myapp`. If the App ID URI doesn’t follow this pattern, setting an application as multi-tenant fails.

Comment: if i get it right, the IdentifierUris most be globally unique ?

Comment: @SaidRahmani Yes, for a multi-tenant application, it must be globally unique.

Comment: can you please explain how make IdentifierUris globally unique

Comment: @SaidRahmani Just as it says in the document. Global uniqueness is enforced by requiring the App ID URI to have a host name that matches a verified domain of the Azure AD tenant.

Comment: ok tanks for your help, can you please tell me how verify App ID URI with domain of the Azure AD tenant ?

Comment: @SaidRahmani You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain