# Error "invalid_client" when trying to get a token from Microsoft API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, windev

I'm trying to develop a drive solution (Onedrive) in a windev program.

I created an application in Microsoft Azure and created a secret key.

[image]

[image]

When doing the first request `https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id={client_id}&scope={scope} &response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}` I'm redirected on the connection page.

Once I'm connected I get a code back as `https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?code={code}.`

But when I ask for a token posting this request : `POST https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&client_secret={client_secret} &code={code}&grant_type=authorization_code`

I get this back

`{ "error":"invalid_client", "error_description":"The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https:\/\/go.microsoft.com\/fwlink\/?linkid=2083908.", "correlation_id":"471e800c-69b4-43c6-a03f-a1f7e9512e6b" }`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means you are using a Microsoft Account to login your client app, but it is not enabled for that.

To change the setting for an existing AD App, navigate to the **Manifest** blade of it in the portal, find the [signInAudience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#signinaudience-attribute) attribute, set it with `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount` or `PersonalMicrosoftAccount`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that but I can't save the manifest when I change that attribut. I get this message : Échec de la mise à jour de l'application BeeImmo. Détail de l'erreur : Le schéma d'URI est non valide ou non pris en charge. [QGW5pi3Jc5avTk0rwGHXi+]

In English it should be: The URI scheme is not valid or not supported.

Comment: @Kazh  Have you changed other configurations of the manifest?

Comment: Not at all. I'm going to post my manifest with hidden ids for you.

Comment: @Kazh  Another way is to select this option when creating the application https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeFdM.png

Comment: @Kazh  I think it may be the reason for replying to the url. You can provide me with the manifest information and let me take a look.

Comment: @Kazh  The problem is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDIWt.png

Comment: To be honest I don't understand where is the problem. Do I have to delete some of these? It's the first time I deal with these api I'm sorry.

Comment: @Kazh  I just found a similar problem, which seems to be related to your `Application ID URI`.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gBvM.png

Comment: @Kazh see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59459255/why-does-signinaudience-azureadmultipleorgs-cause-the-uri-scheme-is-invali

Comment: That was not a problem for me.

See: https://prnt.sc/11x256q

Multi-tenant is enabled.

Comment: @Kazh  What you need is to set up your application to allow personal account login, not just a multi-tenant application. Because you are currently using your personal account to log in to the application.

Comment: @Kazh  You can re-register an application and choose: `Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory-Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)`,  test it .